# Send custom HTTP POST request with cURL or socket_create

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, curl

Is my first time in stackoverflow.

I have a problem.
I try to send this HTTP request with fsockopen:

```
POST /cgi_dte/UPL/DTEUpload HTTP/1.0
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/ms-excel, application/msword, */*
Referer: {url}
Accept-Language: es-cl
Content-Type: multipart/form-data: boundary=9022632e1130lc4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; PROG 1.0; Windows NT 5.0; YComp 5.0.2.4)
Content-Length: {lenght}
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: TOKEN={token}

--9022632e1130lc4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{ndata0}"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit

{data}
--9022632e1130lc4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{ndata1}"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit

{data}
--9022632e1130lc4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{ndata2}"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit

{data}
--9022632e1130lc4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{ndata3}"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit

{data}
--9022632e1130lc4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{filename}"; filename="{file.ext}"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

{xml}

--9022632e1130lc4--

'
```

But PHP show this message:

> Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /srv/http/modfe/sube_envio_y.php on line 81
>
> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://maullin.sii.cl:443 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /srv/http/modfe/sube_envio_y.php on line 81

The PHP code is:

```
$host = "ssl://{url}";
$port = 443;

$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);

if (!$fp) {
    return false;
}
fputs($fp, $string); // &lt;---- $string: the custom HTTP request
stream_set_timeout($fp, 20);
$data = "";
$status = socket_get_status($fp);
while(!feof($fp) && !$status['timed_out']) {
    $data .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    $status = socket_get_status($fp);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Is possible create and send this request with cURL or socket_create()?

Exist other method in php?

PD: my english is bad. excuse me.

Answer (score 3):

Make a note that the url should not contain a path, since the only valid value for that is the host, ie www.yourdomain.com. and not something like www.yourdomain.com/1/demo.php

Answer (score 0):

the error message "name or service not known" indicates that your script is not able to resolve the ip address behind the domain maullin.sii.cl from it's configured DNS server.

Depending on your environment, you might need to configure a proxy to enter the public internet or - in case that script is trying to contact to it's own host - use localhost instead.